# addSubView() and bringSubViewToFront() in viewDidLoad() not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

Im building a application that uses the Google Maps SDK. For that aim I defined the view (root view) as a the mapView. Now I am adding another view which I want to be on top of the mapView, but when I do that in viewDidLoad() its just not happening. I would really appreciate help and even an explanation of why that happens...topViewBar is just a UIView I added in Storyboard.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var topViewBar: UIView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//MARK: - put event on map function

    func putEventOnMAp(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees, eventInfo: String, map: GMSMapView) {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        marker.title = eventInfo
        marker.map = map


    }

//MARK: - Initialize map view
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
                                                      longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView
    self.view.addSubview(topViewBar) // these two lines is where I try to add the additional view
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(topViewBar)


    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `topViewBar` as a subview of `mapView`. I think what you want to do is initialize a simple container `UIView` to set `self.view` to. Then add `mapView` and `topViewBar` both as subviews of the `UIView`.

Comment: Hey Dash. I tried doing that, but than it fails to present the map altogether. I added the map to the root view because that's the only way it allowed me to initialize a map from viewDidLoad. Do you have any idea why this happening?

Comment: Soory, it adds the map. But fails to place a marker. That's why I went with the root view. In any way I'm sure there's a way to add a view on top of it...I think?